# Import scss files from src/assets/ into a component scss file

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, angular6

I have some `scss` files in `src/assets/ap/scss/`:

```
src/
..app/
..assets/
....ap/
......bootstrap/
......scss/
........variable.scss
........grid.scss
........responsive.scss
........style.scss
```

In `src/assets/ap/scss/style.scss`:

```
// depending on the solution, I imagine these need to be updated
@import 'src/assets/ap/scss/variable';
@import 'src/assets/ap/scss/grid';
@import 'src/assets/ap/scss/responsive';
```

In one of my components, I would like to import them like this:

```
// home.component.scss
// depending on the solution, I imagine this needs to be updated
@import './src/assets/ap/scss/style';

// home.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
      '../../assets/ap/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
      './home.component.scss'
   ]
})
```

In `angular.json`:

```
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "styleext": "scss"
  }
},

...

"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

This all compiles fine, but when I load my page, the `scss` styles aren't present. It seems that the `assets` folder aren't being linked up properly. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your angular.json your styles is pointing to **"src/styles.scss"**
i think you should point to "src/assets/ap/scss/style.scss" instead.

```
"styles": [
  "src/assets/ap/scss/style.scss"
],
```

Comment: This works. Does this mean that every "@import" file in a component scss file needs to be included in the angular.json styles?

Comment: Not exactly."styles" option in angular.json is the place where you can specify global styles.You can have multiple local styles using @import "../*/*.scss" imported into a component which will only to be applied to that specific component. You don't need to specify them under "styles" option in angular.json. 
This can be useful for you to understand better.
[Angular-global-styles](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the path in your `angular.json` file as:

```
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/assets/css"
          ]
        },
```

Check more in this [page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10473)